center a signal at 0
In baseband, the carrier frequency is equal to $0$. I have a signal $s(t)=e^{j2\pi \alpha(t)}$ which is shifted in the frequency domain and the expression of $\alpha(t)$ is not given by an explicit formula but can be approximated with a computer code. I would like to center the signal $s(t)$ at $0$ in the frequency domain.
What is the mathematical operation to be performed?

It reeeeeealy needs to define what parameter is being "centered".  Like center of mass?  The centroid of the absolute value of the signal or the centroid of the square of the signal?  (square is proportional to power.)

That's called carrier frequency recovery. There's probably a chapter in the textbook you might be reading on that!

What is the mathematical operation to be performed?

The operation is a frequency shift (so, in frequency domain, a convolution with a Dirac delta at the negative frequency offset, or in time domain the multiplication with a complex exponential of the negative frequency offset), but determining how much you need to shift from the received signal, and how to actually execute that shifting, depends on the properties of your system.

It would seem to me that this carrier frequency would be extracted from the linear trend in the phase-unwrapped $\alpha(t)$.  But there are other ways of defining the center of the spectrum.

@robertbristow-johnson very well put; and as you said under the question, the definition of what a "center" is would be highly contestable without looking at what that "center" is used for or defined by.
